# Find area of square inscribed in region between curve and co-ordinate axes

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

A square having sides parallel to the co-ordinate axes is inscribed in the region $$\{(x,y):x,y>0,y\leq -x^3+3x\}$$
if area of the square can be expressed as $$A^{\frac{1}{3}}+B^{\frac{1}{3}}$$ square units where $A$ and $B$ are integers and $A>B$ , then find $A$ and $B$

**My Attempt**

The vertices of the square can be assumed as $(x_{1},0)(x_{2},0),(x_{1},3x_{1}-x^3_{1}),(x_{2},3x_{2}-x^3_{2})$.

Now $3x_{1}-x^3_{1}=x_{2}-x_{1}=3x_{2}-x^3_{2}$

An attempt to solve leads to the equation $x^6_{1}-9x^4_{1}+21x^2_{1}-3=0$

After this i am not able to do.

Comment: That's a third degree polynomial in $x_1^2$. There's one solution, $x_1^2 = 3 - 2^{1/3} - 2^{2/3}$

Comment: A=216 and B=-108 is the given answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dylan has pointed out, solving the equation gives $$x_1=\sqrt{3-2^{1/3}-2^{2/3}}$$  The height of the square is $$3x_1-x_1^3=3x_1-(3-2^{1/3}-2^{2/3})x_1=(2^{1/3}+2^{2/3})x_1$$ and the area is $$A=(2^{1/3}+2^{2/3})^2(3-2^{1/3}-2^{2/3})=(2^{2/3}+2^{4/3}+4)(3-2^{1/3}-2^{2/3})$$

Multiplying this out and simplifying gives $$A=6-3\cdot2^{2/3}=216^{1/3}-108^{1/3}$$

Comment: The next question might be, how do we solve for $x_1$ without looking up WolframAlpha?

Comment: @Dylan Well, it's a cubic equation, and there's a well-known [formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html) but I see no reason not to use Wolfram Alpha.  It's much less likely to make mistakes than I am.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a problem that you looked it up. I looked it up. I was just starting a discussion that OP might find useful. If was a homework assignment, then one would actually need to do the work in solving the cubic.

Comment: @Dylan No problem.  I too, was just giving my take on things.